# Is there a way to track only object deletes in NHibernate Envers?

Tags: nhibernate-envers

I'd like to configure NHibernate Envers so that only object deletes are audited. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can derive from `AuditEventListener` and override `OnPostInsert`, `OnPostRecreateCollection`, `OnPostUpdate`, `OnPreRemoveCollection`, `OnPreUpdateCollection` and in your impl do nothing in these methods (only keep base class' `OnPostDelete` impl). Then pass in this class as an argument to `configuration.IntegrateWithEnvers([yourEventListenerHere], enversCfg)`.

However, Envers might be overkill for you (you cannot use its query API and other stuff if you just store delete info). Maybe a simple implementation of `IPostDeleteEventListener` is enough in your case (depending on what you want to store)?